# Clear gap between span and table

Tags: html, css

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uryeto61/)**

I can't resolve the gap between a h2 tag and a table. Beside, if you look at my attached image, you will se that in the second table, the first row's width(header) is shorter than the rest, any help is greatly appreciated!

h2 and table css :

```
.tieudemien
{
    line-height: 24px;
    background-color: #80A5CE;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    width:498px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
    margin-left:1px;
}

.tb {
    width: 500px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's result: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/uryeto61/3/
You can just change the padding of class `.tdkq` and `tddd` below:

```
.tdkq, .tddd {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Padding issue:

```
table td {
    padding: 0;   
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/uryeto61/4/

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/uryeto61/2/

add to `table`

```
cellpadding='0'
```

Comment: The [cellpadding attribute is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes). The `<td>` padding should be modified in the CSS.

Comment: @f855a864 - Use `table td{
    padding: 0;   
}` There is no reason to use `cellpadding` in a new project, it is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
table td{
    padding: 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set table td Padding 0

Try This:

```css
body {} table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tb {
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
/*2 cell đầu tiên, xác định độ rộng*/

.tdkq {
  width: 70%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.tddd {
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/*bảng kết quả và đầu đuôi*/

.tbkq {
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  table-layout: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.tbdd {
  width: 100%;
}
.tbdd td {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
/*cột giải và kết quả của bảng kết quả*/

.trkq {
  width: 100%;
}
.thkqgiai {
  width: 20% !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #910000;
}
.thkqso {
  width: 80% !important;
}
.tdkqgiai {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: #910000;
}
.tdkqgiaidb {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #910000;
}
.tdkqso {
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.tdkqsodb {
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  color: red;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
/*cột đầu và đuôi của bảng đầu đuôi*/

.thdddau {
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #910000;
}
.thddduoi {
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #910000;
}
/*tiêu đề cho bảng kq*/

.tieudemien {
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #80A5CE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
.tieudecuoi {
  background-color: #80A5CE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: 300px !important;
}
.tdtieudecuoi {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #80A5CE;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
table td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="tieudemien"> Kết quả xổ số Miền Bắc ngày 02-11-2014</h2>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdkq">
        <table class="tbkq">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="trkq">
              <th class="thkqgiai">Giải</th>
              <th class="thkqso">BTB</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Đặc biệt</td>
              <td class="tdkqsodb">23411</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải nhất</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">37428</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải nh&#236;</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">38460-75356</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải ba</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">02055-66542-36814-52154-66881-20546</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải bốn</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">6300-7736-6062-3408</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải năm</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">0235-2078-1344-6340-4550-6337</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải s&#225;u</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">046-421-944</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải bảy</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">88-98-24-21</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdtieudecuoi"></td>
              <td class="tdtieudecuoi">span</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>


      <td class="tddd">
        <table class="tbdd">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="trkq">
              <th class="thdddau">Đầu</th>
              <th class="thddduoi">Đuôi</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">0</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">0,8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">1</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">1,4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">2</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">8,1,4,1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">3</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">6,5,7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">4</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">2,6,4,0,6,4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">5</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">6,5,4,0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">6</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">0,2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">7</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">8</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">1,8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdkqgiai">9</td>
              <td class="tdkqso">8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```